# Is it the expression “from the floor” correct?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct if I say

> the object loses contact *from the floor*

meaning that the object won’t touch the floor anymore?

Comment: The expression is to *[lose contact with X](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+contact+with)*; if you *lose contact from X*, it is likely to be interpreted that *X* the cause of you losing contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression 'from the floor' is valid, but it usually means something attached to the floor.

> If small areas of asbestos felt come loose from the floor... ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=KP6wqt-WX7sC&pg=PA356&dq=%22loose+from+the+floor%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBmtbqytzJAhXKph4KHbCYBPYQ6AEIHDAA))

Or something above the floor:

> Towel racks, towel dispensers, and other dispensers and disposal units must not be mounted higher than 40 inches from the floor. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=0NyEa_DnYC8C&pg=PA214&dq=%22from%20the%20floor%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvoJHfydzJAhXHPB4KHdrpCKkQ6AEINjAF))

Or "the floor" in public speaking:

> Any nominee from the floor must be an eligible candidate for the director position for which the person has been nominated. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=X3g5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA228&dq=%22from+the+floor%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjslvq5ytzJAhWJLB4KHXVVB7Y4ChDoAQghMAE))

You wouldn't use it for a chair as described.